# Check if atleast one value is entered by user - .Net Validation controls

Tags: asp.net, validation

I've a couple of textboxes in an ASP.NET page and the user is supposed to enter a value in atleast one of these fields before page submit. We had a custom validator for this which throws an error if user hits submit by leaving all fields as empty.

I need to replace the custom validator with other inbuilt .Net validation controls and I would like to know if there is a way to achieve the same. Due to some security reasons, using javascript is not an option.

Here is my customValidator:

```
<asp:customvalidator id="cvSearchCriteria" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Must enter at least one search criteria."></asp:customvalidator>
```

Code Behind:

```
If txtLastName.Text = "" And txtFirstName.Text = "" And txtMiddleInitial.Text = "" _ And ssnTxt.Text = ""
Then cvSearchCriteria.IsValid = False 
End If
```

Comment: Please show how you are currently using your custom validator.

Comment: please give us the code that you tried and the error you received

Comment: We are doing a migration and one of the requirements is to reduce/eliminate the usage of custom validation controls. This is to ensure input data is validated on the client side first so that bad data is not posted back to the server.

Comment: Well then, JavaScript obviously *is* an option.

Comment: As I said, Javascript is not an option for us due to securty reasons. Below is my custom validator.

Comment: <asp:customvalidator id="cvSearchCriteria" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Must enter at least one search criteria."></asp:customvalidator>                                    In the code behind -         If txtLastName.Text = "" And txtFirstName.Text = "" And txtMiddleInitial.Text = "" _
        And ssnTxt.Text = "" Then
            cvSearchCriteria.IsValid = False
        End If

Comment: Your question doesn't make sense. You say you want to replace your working validator with another validator, and you also want to ensure input is validated on client side but you don't want to use JavaScript. Please explain the problem with your working server-side validation.

Comment: You cannot be more right Mr. @MikeSmithDev

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the answer is in the question, this is a typical use of custom validator... as far as I know there is no OOTB multiple-fields validator in .NET